# Task Manager change CPU core display

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

In Windows 10 Task Manager, I have noticed two different behaviors on different machines.  I set the CPU graph to show Logical Processors.  On one machine, I see a "heat map" with the shading of each core getting darker to show instantaneous utilization.  On another machine, each core shows a graph of utilization over time.  What controls this behavior?  I would like to see the graph over time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably the sheer number of cores making it difficult to fit a meaningful graph in the area available. Your "heatmap" CPU has another 16 cores making the graphs very small.

Comment: This might be right. It would be great to find some documentation of this. Expanding the window size does not change the display.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any official Microsoft documentation on why or when Task Manager changes from showing graphs to this "heat map" mode except from an archived post from Microsoft's [Building Windows 8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/b8/using-task-manager-with-64-logical-processors) blog from 2011 with the main reasons being

> - **Lack of real-time comparisons:** When you are looking at a CPU graph for lots and lots of logical processors, it is the anomalies that are interesting. At scale, it is pretty hard to compare moving line graphs of a 60-second window of CPU utilization to understand what is going on.
> - **Tiny graphs:** When you get to the 64+ logical processor range, the graphs get pretty small. If you are trying to figure out which processors are being heavily used, you really have to squint to figure it out. When you get over 256 logical processors, you can barely read the charts at all.

There is no mention of when this changeover occurs but it would seem from the evidence of your screenshots that 64 cores could well be the tipping point.

It seems to be one of those features that was released without much fanfare, after all the market for 64+ core machines was much smaller than it is now.

> A major benefit of a heat map is that it scales really well to large data sets. The new Task Manager will show as many logical processors as the OS supports (up to 640!). To make sure you always see the information at a meaningful size, when the data set gets too big for the window, the heat map scales to best fit, and a scroll bar appears as needed.

Being able to see at a quick glance how many cores are active and how loaded they are can give you an edge and is arguably a lot faster than trying to decipher a lot of tiny graphs to see which ones have a line slightly higher than the others, colour and text is a lot better in this case.

Apparently one of the more useful features is being able to hover over a core and have a top tip show you which core and node it is, presumably so you can then find out what process is stuck overloading particular cores.